# Calendar syncing software for Android or Windows

Tags: windows, android, calendar, synchronization, google-calendar

I want to sync calendars across 2 Android devices.  I don't want to use Google servers.

Is there any Android or Windows software that will support syncing calendars across multiple Android devices?

I would prefer something that will not require an always-running server, as I just need to sync on-demand.  But that's not a hard requirement.

Gratis is always good, but I will consider options with a 1-time payment up to 50 euros/dollars, or an annual payment up to 10 euros/dollars.

Comment: I don't remember the name, but there was something syncing by exporting the calender to `.ics` or something like that to let you sync that p2p. Ah, there it is: [DeSync](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.decsync.cc/) (only on F-Droid and [Github](https://github.com/39aldo39/DecSyncCC)). I've never tried it as I sync with my Nextcloud (which might also be an option, there are providers available). Would DeSync fit?

Comment: @Izzy Oooh... that's a great find.  Thanks!  I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @Izzy BTW, I think you mean DecSync (as opposed to DeSync!).

Comment: my keboad is stck… :D Yes, of course DecSync. At least the links are correct, thanks to copy-paste. Feel free to make it a self-answer with details if it matches – I could not do that well enough as I'm not using it. Please ping me afterwards as I'd like to see, link and most likely upvote :)